# Unity3D as a render server

Tags: php, unity-game-engine, web, rendering, server-side-rendering

I want to make unity3D as a render server.I mean that i have created an application that take video and plays it on the video player of Unity3D ("Something Like Augmented reality"). What i want is to make a server so that user upload their videos from website and it has to be render in unity3d and return back to users. Just i need a guideline how to send uploaded video to unity and how to render it, and send back to user.
My simple website form is

```
<form action="" method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file"/><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>
```

The PHP code looks like.

```
<?php 
$name= $_FILES['file']['name'];

$tmp_name= $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

$position= strpos($name, ".");

$fileextension= substr($name, $position + 1);

$fileextension= strtolower($fileextension);


if (isset($name)) {

$path= 'Uploads/videos/';
if (empty($name))
{
echo "Please choose a file";
}
else if (!empty($name)){
if (($fileextension !== "mp4") && ($fileextension !== "ogg") && ($fileextension !== "webm"))
{
echo "The file extension must be .mp4, .ogg, or .webm in order to be uploaded";
}


else if (($fileextension == "mp4") || ($fileextension == "ogg") || ($fileextension == "webm"))
{
if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $path.$name)) {
echo 'Uploaded!';
}
}
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are asking two seperate questions: how to import user video, and how to export the result.

As for importing the video it's pretty easy, just use videoPlayer.url = path/to/your/file.mp4, on desktop platforms with access to filesystem, this is all you need

As far as output goes, install Unity Recorder package into your project https://unitytech.github.io/unity-recorder/manual/index.html it provides both editor and runtime 'record output to mp4' functionality, and should do what you need